# why are my lollipops sticky?

Tags: candy

I make lollipops at home in a silicon mold but every time as soon as I take them out the mold not even two minutes after they seem to develop a sticky coating how can I prevent that in the first place? I have been dusting a coating of cornstarch but it seems to help temporarily.

Comment: What's the humidity like where you are?

Comment: Hi Jaquelin! Without a recipe, we can only assume that "lolipop" means hard crack candy on a stick, which then makes it the same problem as candy apples on a stick. If you are making something different, jthen it is not a duplicate. You can then edit your recipe into your question (ingredients and method) and we can reopen.